# Launch multiple HTMLViewer Controls isolated

Tags: xojo

I'd like to launch multiple HTMLViewer controls. Each should be manage its own cookie storage. If HTMLViewer_1 is already logged in on a site, e.g. HTMLViewer_2 should be able to log in using another role.

```
Q: How to I isolate HTMLViewer instances against each other?
```